# What is "$ play test" dropdown in circleCI?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, circleci

Im trying to upload my project to circleci but from some reason it fails in a dropdown called "$ play test", I have no idea what is it, and I dont have tests in my project at all.

this is the section im talking about:

[image]

and im getting error there, this is the error:

[image]

I deleted "- sbt test" from my circle.yml so its not that, and I saw another folder of test in play so I thought maybe its that, but its empty, so I created a file in it and put nothing in it and still getting the same error...its driving me crazy ://///

please helpppppp

if you need this is my circle.yml:

```
machine:
  services:
    - docker
  java:
    version: oraclejdk8
  environment:
    SBT_VERSION: 0.13.9
    SBT_OPTS: "-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"

dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - "~/.sbt"
    - "~/.ivy2"
    - "~/.m2"
    - "~/docker"
  pre:
    - wget --output-document=$HOME/bin/sbt-launch.jar https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/"$SBT_VERSION"/sbt-launch.jar
    - echo "java $SBT_OPTS -jar \`dirname \$0\`/sbt-launch.jar \"\$@\"" > $HOME/bin/sbt
    - chmod u+x $HOME/bin/sbt
    - sbt sbt-version
  override:
    - sbt clean update
  post:
    - find . -type f -regex ".*/target/test-reports/.*xml" -exec cp {} $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/ \;
general:
  artifacts:
    - "target/universal/*.tgz"
deployment:
  feature:
    branch: /.*/
    commands:
      - docker login -e admin@something.com -u ${ART_USER} -p ${ART_KEY} docker-local.artifactoryonline.com
      - sbt -DBUILD_NUMBER="${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}" docker:publish
```

Answer (score 3):

CircleCI has a feature called Inference that looks at what language your project is in as well as directories found, file extensions, etc to guess what dependencies and test you have.

If you look to the right of where you saw "play test" you'll see that it says "inference" which means this test was a result of Interference and not `circle.yml`. Inference made an assumption you needed the Play test framework (https://www.playframework.com/) and thus ran a default check, `play test` (the $ is part of the prompt).

If this is not what you want, which looks to be the case, you'll need to override the test command to instead run whatever test you want. This would be something like:

```
test:
  override:
    - echo "This is my test"
    - ./my-custom-command
```

More information: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#test